# Continuity of linear functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C^{1}([0,1])$ and $Y=C([0,1]),$ both with the supremum normn(i.e. $\|x\|=sup_{[0,1]}(|x|)$). Define $F:X\rightarrow Y$ by $F(x)=x+x^{'}$ and $f=x(1)+x^{1}(1)$ for all $x\in X.$ Which of the following is true?

$A.$ $F$ and $f$ are continuous.

$B.$ $F$ is continuous and $f$ is discontinuous.

$C.$ $F$ is discontinuous and $f$ is continuous.

$D.$ $F$ and $f$ are discontinuous.

$E.$ $F$ is closed and $f$ is not closed map.

$G.$ $F$ is not  closed and $f$ is a closed map.

$H.$ Both  $F$ and $f$ are closed.

$I.$ Neither $F$ nor $f$ is closed.

I tried as follows

Consider the sequence $\{x_{n}\}=\{x^{n}\}$ in $X$ which is clearly bounded as bounded by $1.$ But since $\|F(x^{n})\|=\|x^{n}+nx^{n-1}\|$ and $\|f(x^{n})\|=\|1+n\|$ so image sequences are not bounded . Hence both are discontinuous functions. For closeness i  only know that operator $g(x)=x^{'}$ is closed but not continuous.  Am i right ? But i am confused about closeness. Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes right one...

Comment: @M.Van thanks for edit....

Comment: Which norm are you using? The usual norm on $C^1([0,1])$ is $$\| x \| = \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert x(t) \rvert + \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \lvert x'(t) \rvert.$$ With this norm on $X$, both are continuous. However, if you are considering $X$ with just the $\sup$ norm then both are discontinuous, as can be seen by your example.

Comment: yes its just sup norms....

Comment: In the typical norm (that I listed above), the sequence $x_n(t) = t^n$ is no longer a bounded sequence. A sequence of functions converges in that norm if the sequence and the sequences of derivatives both converge uniformly. For example, if $x_n \to x$ and $x_n' \to x'$ uniformly, then clearly $x_n(1) \to x(1)$ and $x_n'(1) \to x'(1)$ which shows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @User8128 please can you tell me which one  of $F$ and $f$ is closed map???